# Simple way to pipe rowsums

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, rowsum

I have the following data frame (showing a head sample)

```
dput(sample)
structure(list(VR1 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, 0L, NA), VR2 = c(NA, 
NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), VR3 = c(NA, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, NA), VR4 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, 0L, NA), VR5 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), VR6 = 
c(NA, 
NA, 0L, NA, 0L, NA), VR7 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, 0L, NA), VR8 = 
c(NA, 
NA, 0L, NA, 0L, NA), VR9 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), VR10 = 
c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, 0L, NA), VR11 = c(NA, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, NA), VR12 = 
c(NA, 
NA, 0L, NA, 0L, NA), VR13 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, 0L, NA), VR14 = 
c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, 0L, NA), VR15 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), VR16 = 
c(NA, 
NA, 0L, NA, 0L, NA), VR17 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, 0L, NA), VR18 = 
c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), VR19 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, 0L, NA), VR20 = 
c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, 0L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = 
"data.frame")
```

I am doing a lot of previous manipulation (such as deleting columns), but I do not find a function to pipe simple rowsums into a new column. Here is what I have been triying
`sample <- sample %>% mutate(total = rowSums(1:20))`

I keep finding on the internet
`sum(c_across`

but R does not recognize it, despite loading tidyverse and dplyr

Comment: One way would be `... total = rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dplyr` option would `c_across()` but it is needed a row id:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
sample %>% mutate(id=1:n())%>%
  rowwise(id) %>%
  mutate(total=sum(c_across(VR1:VR20),na.rm=T))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 22
# Rowwise:  id
    VR1 VR2     VR3   VR4   VR5   VR6   VR7   VR8   VR9  VR10  VR11  VR12  VR13  VR14  VR15  VR16
  <int> <lgl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3     1 NA        0     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     1     0
4    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5     0 NA        0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
6    NA NA       NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# ... with 6 more variables: VR17 <int>, VR18 <int>, VR19 <int>, VR20 <int>, id <int>, total <int>
```

The data used was the `dput(sample)` you shared.

Comment: I think I was not very clear with my question, is not too well formulated. I have solved it now in the following way for anyone's reference `sample<-sample%>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  mutate(vrat_total = rowSums(.[1:20]))` I still do not understand how the ´c_across´ command works and what package it belongs to.